# How to get rid of white margin from the page and make it 100% wide

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem with my page width. Whatever I try it has white margin on the left or right (on the right by default, on the left if I use margin-right:0). 
If I use margin:0 than it stays on the right. 
Tried everything I know and can't get rid of it. Clearing margins using asterix for whole page didn't help, setting width to 100% didn't help. I don't know, maybe the sidenav caused all these issues but I honestly can't see anything like that.

Navbar at the top is fine, it take 100% of the width of the page. Problem starts underneath with the container.

```js
<script>
  function openSlideMenu(){
    document.getElementById('side-menu').style.width = '250px';
    document.getElementById('main').style.marginRight = '250px';
  }

  function closeSlideMenu(){
    document.getElementById('side-menu').style.width = '0';
    document.getElementById('main').style.marginRight = '0';
  }
</script>
```

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
}

body{
  line-height: 1.6em;
  font family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #FFFFF0;
}


.navbar-nav a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #f4f4f4;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: Arial Sans-serif;
  margin: 0 15px 0 15px;
}

.navbar-nav a:hover{
  color:#999999;
}

.navbar-nav{
  margin-left: 180px;
}

.side-nav{
  height:100%;
  width:0;
  position:fixed;
  z-index:1;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  background-color:#111;
  opacity:0.9;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  padding-top:60px;
  transition:0.5s;
}

.side-nav a{
  padding:10px 10px 10px 30px;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-size:22px;
  color:#ccc;
  display:block;
  transition:0.3s;
}

.side-nav a:hover{
  color:#fff;
}

.side-nav .btn-close{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:22px;
  font-size:36px;
  margin-right:50px;
}

#main{
  transition:margin-right 0.5s;
  padding:20px;
  overflow:hidden;
  width:100%;
}

.container{
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #cc0000;
  width:100vw;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Hartstown Huntstown FC | Home</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div style="background-color: #1a1a1a;">
    <div class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index1.html"><img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="Company logo"></a>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="history.html">HISTORY</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="contact.php">CONTACT</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="teams.html">TEAMS</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="gallery.html">GALLERY</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="https://www.balondirect.com/club-shop/hartstown-huntstown-fc.html">SHOP</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <span class="open-slide">
          <a href="#" onclick="openSlideMenu()">
            <svg width="30" height="30">
                <path d="M0,5 30,5" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="5"/>
                <path d="M0,14 30,14" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="5"/>
                <path d="M0,23 30,23" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="5"/>
            </svg>
          </a>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="side-menu" class="side-nav">
  <a href="#" class="btn-close" onclick="closeSlideMenu()">&times;</a>
  <a href="index1.html">Home</a>
  <a href="history.html">History</a>
  <a href="contact.php">Contact</a>
  <a href="teams.html">Teams</a>
  <a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a>
  <a href="https://www.balondirect.com/club-shop/hartstown-huntstown-fc.html">Shop</a>
</div>

<div class="container" id="main">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem unde repellendus reiciendis illo ipsam labore nostrum nihil assumenda magni quod hic saepe accusantium, quam nemo illum, dicta harum! Commodi rem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. </p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably the Bootstrap `container` class adding your white space. You should `inspect` the elements in Chrome, and it will tell you which CSS is operating on that particular element.

For a full width container, you should probably be using the Bootstrap `container-fluid` class.

It is rarely a good idea to modify the CSS for a main bootstrap class such as `container`. It is better to add additional classes or id with your own rules.

```html
<div class="container container--mysite" id="main">
```

i.e. in the above you have added a modifier class called `container--mysite`. If you have problems with CSS specificity/priority just be more specific.

e.g.

```css
.container--myapp { myrules}
// if the above doesn't work, try...
#main .container { myrules }
.container .container--mysite {myrules}
```

will produce CSS which overrides the standard Bootstrap rules for the standard container class

In order to have some structure in your CSS, look up 'Block Element Modifier CSS' if you're not using SASS/LESS to create your CSS.

Comment: It looks like it is Bootstrap container as I just changed the class from container to something else and suddenly problem is gone. Just out of curiosity. Would you know how to overwrite Bootstrap container qualities using the same class?

Comment: For a full width container you should probably be using `container-fluid` instead of just `container`